# ActiveAdmin Redirect if not an admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I would like to create a simple redirect for admin:false Users who are willing to go to /admin pages. I am using ActiveAdmin and a single User model with a admin:bool flag. I tried the following:

in my AA init file

```
config.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
```

in my App controller

```
def authenticate_admin_user!
  redirect_to root_path unless current_user.try(:is_admin?)
end
```

And nothing happens.

I also tried creating a custom method like this in a new `ActiveAdmin::AuthorizationAdapter` but could not figure out how to use it

```
def authorized?(action, subject = nil)
  user.admin?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In my case active admin provide `current_admin_user` not `current_user`

```
def authenticate_admin_user!
  redirect_to root_path unless current_admin_user.try(:is_admin?)
end
```